# Generalized Linear Least Squares

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation-theory

I've run across a problem which asks me to calculate a best fit line through data using a 'generalized linear least squares' approach where, instead of minimizing the residual:

$\vec{r} = \vec{b} - A\vec{X}$

we minimize the residual in:

$B\vec{r} = \vec{b} - A\vec{X},$

where $B$ is an symmetric positive definite matrix.

Is this a standard practice in approximation?  Can anyone explain what this $B$ matrix is doing in terms of the approximation?  Would the standard normal equation still apply (after multiplying through by $B^{-1}$)?

Comment: This is scaling in  a general sense. For example, some residuals may be in miles, some in inches, so it may make sense to adjust the residual trade-offs accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  In what kind of situation would you need a whole matrix of scaling factors (e.g. If each your data points was in a different unit)?  Why is it applied to the residual though?  Does it make more sense to apply the 'scaling matrix' as an inverse to the other side of the equation (since these are the 'points' that we are scaling)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the problem is to minimize $r^T V^{-1} r$ where V is the covariance matrix which allows for correlations and non-constant variances. B is sort of the square root of $V^{-1}$. Not sure why it has been introduced in this context.